# How can I set lookup values to a XSLT variable and call the variable to display according to condition?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, 2016, xslt

I am trying to declare a variable and set the xsl:value-of lookup column and later compare the stored value using conditions. I am facing issues while declaring and calling variables. This I am using to display a custom form in SharePoint 2016 using following code.

```
<xsl:variable name="storevalue" select="substring-before(substring-after(@Name_x0020_Name_x003a_Is, '&gt;'), '&lt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$storevalue='ABZ'">
    <span style="color:red;">$storevalue</span>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <span style="color:green;">$storevalue</span>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below code for assigning variable and calling its value.

```
  <xsl:variable name="StoreValue">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@LookUpFieldName, '&gt;'), '&lt;/a&gt;')" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="($StoreValue == 'ABZ')"> 
       <span style="color:red;"> 
          <xsl:value-of select="@StoreValue"/> 
       </span>
    </xsl:when> 
    <xsl:otherwise> 
       <span style="color:green;"> 
          <xsl:value-of select="@StoreValue"/> 
       </span>
    </xsl:otherwise> 
  </xsl:choose>
```